# PayPal Pro/Express Omnipay Gateway - Credit Card Invalid Headers

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a problem testing sandbox credit card on my PayPal Pro/Express Omnipay Gateway. I am using October CMS which runs on Laravel and as I understand it uses the Laravel plugins for PayPal payments.

Now the problem is that I have username, password and signature credentials, but I took them from my live PayPal account. Problem is that I can't find the same credentials on sandbox PayPal account. I found the credentials in this page: https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/mytools/apiaccess/firstparty/signature

Now at the checkout process I get a response from PayPal which says:

> "Security header is not valid"

As I understand I get this because I use live credentials on testing environment, but how can I get the sandbox credentials to test this?

Thank you.

Comment: PAYPAL credentials can be found under Sandbox -> Accounts -> Profile -> API Credentials

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much, now it works. :) Add this as an answer so I can accept it. @jeprubio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PAYPAL credentials can be found under `Sandbox` -> `Accounts` -> `Profile` -> `API Credentials`.

Notice they might have to be url encoded ( http://www.php.net/urlencode ) before sending them.